# Creating an union-like related models

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django app with a model called `OS` (as in "Operating System"). The model has some usual fields, like `name` or `version`. Those fields are common to all operating systems.

I also have two other (related) models, called `Linux` and `Windows`. Those have some OS-specific fields (`Linux` has a `desktop_environment`, as in "KDE" or "Gnome", `apps_manager`, as in "apt", pacman", etc...; `Windows` has a `built_in_antivirus` field, etc...). This means that those two models have completely different fields, that make sense only for specific operating systems.

The `OS` model has a OneToOne relation with both the `Linux` and the `Windows` models, but only one of those 2 actually exists (an OS can't be Linux and Windows at the same time).

How can I create some sort of "relation", "attribute", "manager" or XYZ property so I can access the fields of `Linux` and `Windows` from an instance of an `OS` model?

Example:

```
a = OS.objects.get(pk=3) # This is a Windows instance
a.<magic>.built_in_antivirus
True

b = OS.objects.get(pk=14) # This is a Linux instance
b.<magic>.desktop_environment
```

Please note that I don't want to move all fields to the same model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-methods) for this.

You will have to change your `models.py`:

class OS(models.Model):
    ''' Your OS Model '''
    # your fields go here

```
@property
def magic_property(self):
    ''' Here is your magic property ''' 
    if hasattr(self, 'linux_related_name'):
        # This has Linux related model
        return self.linux_related_name
    if hasattr(self, 'windows_related_name'):
        # This has Window related model
        return self.windows_related_name
    return None
```

Now you can access your property using `obj.magic_property`